# celery with rabbitmq why to start the celery process

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Trying to understand how celery works with rabbitmq from [the following link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-celery-with-rabbitmq-to-queue-tasks-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

code:

```
from celery import Celery

app=Celery('tasks',backend='amqp',broker='amqp://')

@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def print_hello():
    print 'hello'
    for i in xrange(2,222222):
        print i

print_hello()
```

Questions:

1. What is the use for running `celery worker -A celery_test -n 1.%h &`? I can run the python script directly.
2. What if want to read the result in the called function like:

   ```
   from celery import Celery

   app=Celery('tasks',backend='amqp',broker='amqp://')

   @app.task()
   def print_hello(n):
       print 'hello'
       for i in xrange(2,n):
           print i
       # continue the code from here after the above processing
   ```

Comment: sorry - can you rephrase question 1 - it's not totally clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. **What is the use for running `celery worker -A celery_test -n 1.%h &`? I can run the python script directly.**

You can run the script directly, that's right, but you have to do it manually.

Celery works this way:

- You have one or more workers running somewhere;
- An application needs to ask a worker to do some task. It puts a message on a queue (RabbitMQ in this case).
- Celery gets the message and asks one of the workers to execute the task.

Now of course I've omitted some details (Celery offers many interesting features), what I wanted to say is that Celery is about launching tasks from an application to a cloud of workers.

So, there's no benefit in running scripts manually. You should launch tasks remotely for Celery to be useful.

> 2. **What if want to read the result in the called function like, [...]**

You have to remove `ignore_result=True` (which you already did). Then from the application that launched the task you can retrieve the result once the task is complete. Excerpt from the [guide you are following](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-celery-with-rabbitmq-to-queue-tasks-on-an-ubuntu-vps):

> To check whether the task is complete, we can use the `.ready` method:
>
> [...]
>
> We can get the value by using the `.get` method.

Note that `.get` will give you the *return value* of the task, not the output. Your `print_hello()` is producing output, but is not returning anything: `.get` will return `None`.

If you want to get the result from somewhere else (not from the application that launched the task), you can use [the `task_id`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-task-if-i-have-the-id-that-points-there).

Comment: You have one or more workers running somewhere: Do you mean workers as celery tasks?  also if the tasks are taken care automatically then is there no need to run the command celery worker -A celery_test -n 1.%h & ????

Comment: @Rajeev: tasks are your Python functions; workers are processes that execute such tasks as required.

Comment: k sure.But are you saying we need not run this command explicitly? or why is this command run?  celery worker -A celery_test -n 1.%h &

Comment: @Rajeev: yes, you have to run that command: it is needed to start a worker. If you do not have a worker, who is going to execute your tasks?

Comment: But again that is a manual process right? i.e, starting a worker.But after the worker completes the task the worker will still be alive right?

Comment: @Rajeev: sure. The worker will wait for tasks until you manually stop it. The role of Celery is to orchestrate workers and make them run tasks. Starting/stopping them is your duty

Answer (score 1):

1. The idea of celery is that tasks are run asynchronously in separate processes, called "workers", possibly on many machines. The app where you schedule the task (the python script you run) does not have to know anything about your setup: where the workers actually run, how many of them, etc. That's why you have to start the workers yourself with `celery worker`.

   In your script, you call the task synchronously, so it is executed immediately, not queued in rabbitmq and handed off to the workers. In the context of a web app you will need to schedule the task differently (consult the Celery documentation about [calling tasks](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html)).
2. Celery can store the result of a task in a [result storage](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-states).

Answer (score 1):

for question 2:

```
from path.to module import print_hello

task_result = print_hello.apply_async((10,), {})
result = task_result.get()
```